# Scrape OneNote Web App page

Tags: onenote

I'm really liking many things about OneNote however, to really use it to the full, I need to be able to at least Scrape data from OneNote web app pages. They make pretty ingenious use of javascript to emulate the Desktop UI. I would love to be able to read/write data on these pages. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something with [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/)?

Or wait until the [RESTful API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn575437.aspx) allows reading? Is there something you need to do that can only be achieved by scraping?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the REST API: https://dev.onenote.com/docs  It does support reading and you can get a large portion of page content, which is at parity (or close to it) with what is on the web content. Not to mention it is easier to parser with a structured schema.